# Calculating switching loss of diode - unknown Qrr

Tags: diodes, switch-mode-power-supply, switching-losses

I would like to calculate a switching power loss of BY203-20S diode, in following conditions:

Vr = 1600 V, 
fsw = 65 kHz

Switching loss of a diode is given by equation:

\$Psw = Vr*fsw*Qrr\$

We can substitute for the reverese recovery charge:

\$Qrr = (Trr*Irrm)/2\$

However, value of Qrr nor Irrm is given in the datasheet of BY203-20S, only value Trr = 300 ns is given.

If I choose arbitrary value of 1 A for Irrm, switching loss yields in huge value of about 15.6 W, which of course the tiny package can't handle.

Is there some way to estimate the Irrm or Qrr to calculate the switching loss more accurately?

Comment: Use a simulator and hone your model until you are happy with it. Press go.

Comment: I'd contact Vishay and ask them if they have any characterization data on Qrr.

Comment: Usually when something like that isn't specified, it's because they don't want to talk about it because it isn't a very good value.  But you can always ask them.